# How to fix a query using the date() function

Tags: sqlite

when I use the sqlite3 query:

select * from readings where rdate >= date('now','localtime','-30 day')

it returns the entire database and not the last 30 days.

rdate is stored as an integer in the database like 2018/12/01 04:20

I really don't care about the time just the date.

Comment: Look at the format of the string returned by `date()`. Look at the strings in the rdate column. Are they the same format? If not, they can't be meaningfully compared.

Comment: They are all the same format and all the same length. yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm

Comment: That's not what `date()` returns.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how you would write it so I get a list of all the records that are from 90 days before now to now? Thank you

Comment: I'd start by storing timestamps in a format that sqlite functions recognize. Then it's really easy to do. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype

Comment: Okay. Thanks for trying to help. But I am new to SQLite and have no idea what you are saying. I know MySQL pretty well and this is what I use with my MySQL database that works great. SELECT SUM(hist) FROM readings WHERE rdate > now() - interval 91 day AND rtype = 0. But having trouble getting it to work in SQLite

Comment: MySQL is not sqlite. Sqlite is not MySQL. They do many things differently. Read the documentation. Pay attention to the date and time formats understood by sqlite functions. Use those formats. Only compare values of the same format.

Comment: Your so much help thx.